# Reading Excel file to dataframe and copying last non-empty column value to empty cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to read an Excel table to a dataframe. The table contains some empty cells which come up as whitespaces in the data frame. I would like these empty cells to be filled with the last set value (preceding the empty cells) from the same columns. I can do it with three lines of code which pretty much do the job but look a bit cumbersome. I wonder if there is a way of doing it in a more accurate way? At least set the key in read_excel to convert empty cells to NA?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\test\play.xlsm', sheet_name = 'C.1',
                   skiprows = 11, nrows = 52, usecols = 'B:I', header = None, na_values = r'^\s*$')

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df[1] = pd.Series(df[1]).fillna(method='ffill')

print(df.head(20))
```

Original dataframe

```
10  iC5          i-Pentane   1.205  0.553   1.243   3.350   1.238   2.118
11  nC5          n-Pentane   1.787  0.821   1.331   3.587   1.385   2.368
12   C6            Hexanes   4.946  2.714   1.317   4.207   1.738   3.549
13        Me-Cyclo-pentane   1.471  0.788   0.235   0.739   0.381   0.761
14                 Benzene   0.126  0.063   0.021   0.062   0.034   0.062
15            Cyclo-hexane   2.487  1.332   0.428   1.347   0.672   1.340
16   C7           Heptanes   7.109  4.534   0.475   1.768   1.258   2.987
17         Me-Cyclo-hexane   6.220  3.888   0.374   1.372   1.066   2.481
18                 Toluene   1.286  0.754   0.065   0.225   0.210   0.458
19   C8            Octanes  10.151  7.381   0.235   0.997   1.407   3.810
```

Dataframe that I need to get:

```
10  iC5          i-Pentane   1.205  0.553   1.243   3.350   1.238   2.118
11  nC5          n-Pentane   1.787  0.821   1.331   3.587   1.385   2.368
12   C6            Hexanes   4.946  2.714   1.317   4.207   1.738   3.549
13   C6   Me-Cyclo-pentane   1.471  0.788   0.235   0.739   0.381   0.761
14   C6            Benzene   0.126  0.063   0.021   0.062   0.034   0.062
15   C6       Cyclo-hexane   2.487  1.332   0.428   1.347   0.672   1.340
16   C7           Heptanes   7.109  4.534   0.475   1.768   1.258   2.987
17   C7    Me-Cyclo-hexane   6.220  3.888   0.374   1.372   1.066   2.481
18   C7            Toluene   1.286  0.754   0.065   0.225   0.210   0.458
19   C8            Octanes  10.151  7.381   0.235   0.997   1.407   3.810
```

Again, the code works but looks ugly. I wonder if there is a way to make regex working in "na_values" key?

Comment: if u want empty cells to be read as ```NaN```, you can set na_values in ur read_excel option :```pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsx', na_values=[""])``` this will read empty cells as null, in addition to the preset null values  [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#na-values)

Comment: Somehow the empty cells were not empty but with one space in them. So I had to add space to your solution as na_values=[" "]. Does it mean that regex style "^\s*$" isn't working in na_values?

Comment: i dont think u can pass regex to na_values. it has to be defined characters. or it might literally looking for the characters instead of interpreting them as regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want one line solution `Series` constructor is not necessary, `replace` is used only for this column and last is possible use `ffill` for shorcut of `.fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
df[1] = df[1].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
```